# Object initialization with validation

Tags: c#, validation, oop, initialization

I have a simple `object` that looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    private readonly string csvData;
    public Product(string _csvData)
    {
        csvData = _csvData;
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

This is created with a `CSV string` received from the application user.
so for this `CSV`: `5,Orange,7` the `pruductId` will be 5, the `Name` will be orange etc...

My problem is that I need to validate the `CSV` before initializing the `Product`, and in case of an error I need to know what it was (return it?).
This is how I validate the `CSV` (this method is found inside the `Product` class):

```
    public string ValidateCSV()
    {
        string[] splitCsv = csvData.Split(',');

        if (splitCsv.Length != 3)
            return "Csv error";

        if (!splitCsv[0].IsNumeric())
            return "Id error";

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

My question is what is the preferred(in terms of proper `OO` and safety) approach to `initialize` my `Product` and validate it?
Should I add an `InitError` property and check it after the initialization?
Should I create a `GetProduct` method?

Comment: throw the appropriate exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I'll remove the constructor with `csvData`. Why on earth a product has to know about where does it comes from? It could be CSV, Database, XML, etc. It makes no sense to have it as a field in `Product` class.

Then create a `ProductFactory` (or a `ProductParser`) with single method which creates the `Product` out of CSV, if anything wrong, it should throw exception. When `ProductFactory` returns a product, it should be in a valid state.

Comment: So the `ProductFactory` should be a separate class that contains a method that returns the appropriate object and the validation should occur inside of this method (or be called by this method)?

Comment: If you go this route, it's still a good idea to make the validation logic (that doesn't throw an exception) accessible separately from the method that creates the object (see my answer below).

Comment: @Yoav Exactly. We separate the responsibility of object creation to `ProductFactory`. It will validate and throw exception if necessary (Or validation can be in separate method), and that only returns a `Product` when everything is okay(Data is in expected format).

Comment: The reason validation must be available separately is so that e.g. the UI can test the validity of user input without attempting to create the object.  And I believe it shouldn't throw an exception because exceptions are relatively expensive, and shown only be throw when an unexpected thing has occurred. A typing error by a user is not an unexpected thing:  it is to be expected.

Comment: @RichardPawson You can use `TryXXX` pattern in that case. i.e `bool TryCreateProduct(string csvData, out Product product)`. This way you can avoid the cost of exceptions

Comment: @Sriram That doesn't solve it -  because if OK the product is automatically created.  Think of a UI form where the user must enter the CSV data and other fields.  You need to validate the CSV without creating the product, and then validate other fields, but you still want that validation logic to be on the Product

Comment: @RichardPawson Fair enough. Agree with you.

Comment: @RichardPawson so creating a method that returns a string with the error and using it once in the `GUI` side and again in the creation method is the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Create the option for two-level validation:

1. Make the ValidateCSV method static so that whatever is creating the new Product (e.g. the UI) can call that method before attempting to create the product.
2. Then, separately, call the validation inside the constructor, and throw an exception if it fails.

Comment: And what would the point be of validating the data before calling the method that will create the object, given that that method is just going to run the validation again? Fact is: the attempt to create the product is itself the act of validation. There's no need to do it twice, and you _have_ to do when creating the object (though not necessarily in the constructor...IMHO it is better to follow Sriram's advice to keep the constructor data-source-agnostic).

Comment: @Peter I've answered this fully in comments on Sriram's answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's an interesting strategy. But it doesn't take into account scenarios where GUI validation is not desired, nor where the GUI code itself is isolated from the underlying business logic (hence the GUI code is expected to implement and execute its own validation...you don't want a web form wasting time over the network to validate input, but you don't want the server to leave all validation up to the web form). This seems very scenario-specific to me, however reasonable an approach it might be in some cases.

Comment: " it doesn't take into account scenarios where GUI validation is not desired"  Not sure what you mean, since my recommendation doesn't militate against such a situation at all.

Comment: @Peter ... so I'm not sure what your point it. "you don't want a web form wasting time over the network to validate input,"  Given the current prevalence of web-forms providing server-based auto-complete on many fields I would say this is becoming less of an issue, and it must be weighed against the peril of having duplicating any business logic/rule on both client and server. As the author of 'naked objects' I should probably declare my bias toward 'behaviourally-complete domain objects' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Separate *data* and its *representation*; CSV is just a *representation* (and that's why *should not be stored* in the object) of *actual data* that is `ProductId`, `Name`, `Quantiry` values:

```
public class Product {
  // You don't need any CSV here: CSV is the representation of the data
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }

  // Just a constructor: no CSV at all
  public Product(): base() {
  }

  public static Product FromCsv(String csvValue) {
    //TODO: Parse csvValue here, throw ArgumentException on incorrect csvValue
    if (null == csvValue)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("csvValue");
    ...  

    Product result = new Product();

    //TODO: Assign ProductId, Name, Quantity properties here
    result.ProductId = ...

    return result; 
  }

  public String ToCsv() {
    // Simplest implementation, Name is not expected to have either ',' or '"'
    return ProductId.ToString() + "," + Name + "," + Quantity.ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd throw an exception:

```
public class Product
{
    private readonly string csvData;
    public Product(string _csvData)
    {
        csvData = _csvData;

        ValidateCSV()
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public void ValidateCSV()
    {
        string[] splitCsv = csvData.Split(',');

        if (splitCsv.Length != 3)
            throw new ArgumentException("CVS should contain 3 values, only contained " + splitCsv.Length);

        if (!splitCsv[0].IsNumeric())
            throw new ArgumentException("The first item should be a number");

        //Possibly populate the class as well if it checks out
        ProductId = int.Parse(splitCsv[0]); // could be combined with the check with something like TryParse
        Name = splitCsv[1];
        Quantity = int.Parse(splitCsv[2]); // We didn't validate this one
    }
}
```